# Train Model with same image in diferents orientation

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, coreml

It is a good a idea to train the model with the same images , but with diferents orientations? I a have a small set of images for the training thats the reason why Im trying to cover all the mobile camera-gallery user scenarios.

For example, the image: example.png with 3 copies; example90.png, example180.png and example.270.png with their diferents rotations. And also with diferents background colors, shadows, etc.

By the way, my test is to identify the type of animal.

Is that a good idea??

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. But in general I'd say yes, this is a form of data augmentation. Please add more details if you want a precise answer, as it is your question is too broad.

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm just worried about training the model focused on the same set of images, and that the model only positively recognizes the images very similar to the training set

Answer (score 0):

If you use Core ML with the Vision framework (and you probably should), Vision will automatically rotate the image so that "up" is really up. In that case it doesn't matter how the user held their camera when they took the picture (assuming the picture still has the EXIF data that describes its orientation).